# How to redeem California tax income return warrants?

Tags: california, income-tax-refund, warrants

During 2016, I have overestimated my state taxes; as a result, the state of California have issued a "tax refund warrant". This is what it looks like (with personal identifiers removed):

[image]

So, in general I really like the state of California; but we do dollar$ around these parts. How can I turn this piece of paper into numbers on my bank account,  preferably digitally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your CA Tax Warrants are registered warrants, per this [CA Franchise Tax Board page](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/aboutFTB/newsroom/Registered_Warrants.shtml) you can redeem the warrants with the State Treasurer's Office:

> Effective September 4, 2009, State of California registered warrants
>   issued by the State Controller are redeemable.
>
> In order to receive any interest earned when you redeem your
>   registered warrant, use the address below to either present the
>   warrant in person or mail it to the State Treasurer's Office.
>
> **Attention**: Registered Warrant Desk State Treasurer's Office
>
> 915 Capitol Mall
>
> Sacramento, CA 95814

According to [this blog post](http://www.mymoneyblog.com/how-to-redeem-california-iou.html), you can also:

- Redeem at major banks
- Pay other California tax bills